# rendering colours in PDF generation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf-generation, chromium, grover-gem

two snippets of code  are leading to the same result

```
<span style='color: rgb(255, 0, 0); ' >  [...]</span>


<div class='tree_vertical_father'> [...] </div>

*where*
.tree_vertical_father {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.07);
}
```

background color is not applied and the color of the font is black.

The PDF is being generated with the grover gem that uses pupetter and thus chromium to generate a view then converted to a PDF.

When the view is generated in the browser, all colours are rendered as expected.

what is required to make Chromium accept the color styling?

Comment: ` print_background` is in practice not documented (see answer below).  Useful to point out the motivation.  I will add that 'ageing' or fatigued eyes makes dark mode extremely appealing == mandatory consideration. IMHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watch for `media` type, if you have it set to `screen` it will not show in pdf, which by default is `print`:

```html
<span style="color: rgb(255, 0, 0);">[...]</span>
<div class="tree_vertical_father">[...]</div>

<!--                         vvvvvvvv -->
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
  .tree_vertical_father {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.07);
  }
</style>
```

Backgrounds are off by default:

```rb
Grover.new("http://localhost:3000",
  path: "localhost.pdf",
  print_background: true,    # enable backgrounds
  emulate_media: "screen"    # set media if needed
).to_pdf
```

*https://github.com/Studiosity/grover?tab=readme-ov-file#configuration*

*https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api/puppeteer.pdfoptions.md#properties*

Comment: Very thorough and helpful answer. I had missed the emulate_media attribute, however some complimentary info:           `print_background` is not documented *per se* in the gem repo and only shows up in a single place in the code https://github.com/search?q=repo%3AStudiosity%2Fgrover%20print_background&type=code  and is referenced for pupeteer as `printBackground`.